# Not able make an api callout from apex but working in postman collection

Tags: http, salesforce, http-status-code-404, apex

A 404 status code indicates that the requested resource was not found on the server. In this case, the API endpoint https://stage.northernarc.com/it/api/nuscore/createPartner could not be found, which is why the request failed.

Failed to create partner. Status code: 404
15:56:19.402 (1402791622)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|01pBl0000009k21|className.methodnamwe()
System.HttpResponse[Status=Not Found, StatusCode=404]

i want to know the reason